# Is it okay to override (hide) a non-virtual method but still call it explicitly from a child class?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, overriding

Is it okay to override (hide) a non-virtual method but still call it explicitly from a child class? [It works](http://ideone.com/sobXR5) but I don't know if it's compiler-specific or should be avoided for one reason or another. (I didn't expect it to work based on the terminology of "hiding" functions.)

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "A::foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "B::foo()" << endl;
        A::foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

---

#### Edit

This might focus the question more.

The parent's non-virtual method is in an infrastructure library we can't change, yet we need to derive a class that *hides* (not "overrides," as I've learned now) a function in favor of one that augments it (and calls the parent one explicitly en route). That is, the derived class *requires* this "augmented" function to be used in place of the parent one. **Is this a valid scenario in which to hide a parent function?**

Comment: yes, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: This is a standardized part of the language. I would consider not hiding non-virtual methods in the first place, though, since you could run into trouble if anyone takes a pointer or reference to the base class.

Comment: Just fyi, I would prefer to encapsulate an A as a member variable of B than to derive a B from an A, where possible.  I have spent a lot of time dealing with impossible tangles caused by inheritance and base class behaviour in the past.  So use it with care.

Comment: @Robinson - That sounds like a much better approach and I think we'll do that. Still, curious to know whether the scenario I describe in my previous comment is a valid case for hiding parent functions.

Comment: It's fine, as Luchian shows.

Comment: @Robinson - Turns out we couldn't go that route (encapsulating) because we do have to override a different (virtual) function. (It's a generic timer class that requires overriding the Timeout() function. We needed to augment the StartTimer() function to set up some variables for said Timeout() function.) So, we're going with hiding the parent function. Good to know about the encapsulating alternative for the future, however. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's okay, but you're not overriding. You're hiding, as you already mentioned. Overriding means polymorphism will work on your object, and in your case, it won't.

For example:

```
A* a = new B;
a->foo();
```

will call the method `A::foo()`, whereas if you were to override the method (by making it `virtual`), it would call `B::foo()`.

Also note that there might be issues related to the actual signature, for example if you had the method `B::foo(int)`, you wouldn't be able to call `foo(void)` on a `B` object directly.